# Sql query regarding adding more information into existing query

Tags: sql

```
Select c1.Eventid, c1.Place, c1.competitornum, c2.competitornum
From Results c1, Results c2
Where c1.Place = c2.Place
and c1.Eventid = c2.Eventid
and c1.competitornum < c2.competitornum
```

The following query allows the competitors who tied in an event to be displayed from a hypothetical table 'results'.  i.e. got the same placing in an event.

I need to extend the query to show more details about the event - and in place of the event id, I need to display the eventgender, distance and style from hypothetical other/2nd table, 'Events'.

How to I extend the query to include the necessary information from the Events table?

Comment: Long shot here, but this is homework, isn't it? I've seen a number of similar queries and table structures recently...

Answer (score 1):

To display data from relating tables you can **[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)** them.

```
Select e.eventgender, e.distance, e.style, 
       c1.Place, c1.competitornum, 
       c2.competitornum
From Results c1, Results c2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events e ON e.Eventid = c1.Eventid
Where c1.Place = c2.Place
and c1.Eventid = c2.Eventid
and c1.competitornum < c2.competitornum
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming in Events table has an Eventid column.

```
SELECT X.*, e.eventgender, e.distance , e.style
FROM Events e
INNER JOIN
        (Select c1.Eventid, c1.Place, c1.competitornum, c2.competitornum
        From Results c1, Results c2
        Where c1.Place = c2.Place
        and c1.Eventid = c2.Eventid
        and c1.competitornum < c2.competitornum)X
ON x.Eventid = e.Eventid
```